# How to run NUnit test in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: continuous-integration, nunit, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

When I try to execute **NUnit** test in VSTS task I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: The path 'C:\a\1\s\INCASOL.IP\packages' specified in the 'TestAdapterPath' does not contain any test adapters, provide a valid path and try again.
```

I have these tasks in VSTS:

[image]

The "Run unit test" task is configured as follows:
[image]

Note I have set the "Path to Custom Test Adapters".

I think the dlls for NUnit are properly copied to packages folder because in "Nuget restore" task I can see the following:

```
Added package 'NUnit.2.6.4' to folder 'C:\a\1\s\INCASOL.IP\packages'
```

Notes: The NUnit version is 2.6.4 and I'm using Hosted Agent

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After a few hours looking for a solution, I solved it few minutes after having asked my question.
Although I could run my test in my local machine using NUnit Test Adapter, this package hadn't been added to my packages folder. So, once I run

```
Install-Package NUnitTestAdapter
```

for my test projects, everything works fine.

Comment: After installing the adapter how do you use visual studio to run a single test ?

Comment: You can configure a Task in your build pipeline to run your tests